# matching key in ngfor

Tags: angular, typescript

I just want to know it is possible to match key in `*ngfor`.
This is my example code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngfor-index-example-8qkxmv). When I use this method it just display `No data`

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses; index as i">
     {{key == course.id? course.name :'No data' }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Component**

```
  courses = [
    { id:1, name:'course1' },
    { id:2, name:'course2' },
    { id:3, name:'course3' }
  ];
  key = [1,2];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`key` is an array. You need to check course id existence.

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let course of courses; index as i">
     {{ key.includes(course.id) ? course.name :'No data' }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `{{key.includes(course.id) ? course.name :'No data' }}` shorter